# Нужна ли запятая между именем и личным местоимением?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, ссп, местоимения

1. У Олега затряслись руки(,) и он сказал: «Вы с ума сошли?»
2. У Екатерины непроизвольно вышли газы(,) и она смущённо произнесла: «Это не я».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это обычные сложносочинённые предложения. Запятая ставится перед союзом ***и***, соединяющим две основы: *руки затряслись, он сказал; газы вышли, она произнесла*.

Следующее примечание не относится к предложениям из вопроса, но всё же, как говорится, на всякий случай:

> **Примечание.** Перед союзом *и* **запятая** ставится также в тех случаях, когда он присоединяет предложение, в котором подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, относящимся к подлежащему первой части сложносочиненного предложения или повторяющим его: *Вдали по-прежнему машет крыльями мельница, **и** всё ещё она похожа на маленького человечка, размахивающего руками* (Ч.); *Ты всегда был строг ко мне, **и** ты был справедлив* (Т.).

См.: [Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133) (справочник Розенталя).